# Vehicle or smartphone tracking

Tags: qgis-plugins, software-recommendations

I was looking for some plugin in QGIS which would help me tracking smartphone (for vehicle tracking system). I could find posiview in qgis. It has very sketch help file and therefore could not configure the application.

Comment: This is more of a statement than a question. The `software-recommendations` tag is a bit of trap here in GIS SE, because they are too subjective to fit our "Focused question / Best answer" model. There is a  [softwarerecs.se] group, but you should read their Tour before posting, much the way you should read our [tour].